# How to add multiple Client ID's in Google SSO Integration in iOS App

Tags: ios, google-sso

I am a complete beginner in iOS development. I want to integrate google SSO in my App. I have a requirement where there are multiple clients with different client ID’s and different users in it. I am confused as how I can implement that?
Is there another way to add client ID's in our project other than URL Scheme? Like we define Client ID in a variable or something and use different client ID’s based on different conditions? Also is there any way I can change client ID’s dynamically? I know we can not modify Url scheme on run time but is that possible?

I can easily add one client ID and the app works great.